# Debezium Connector for PostgreSQL introduces \ in topic data of type JSON

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am new to kafka and would like to get some advice on this problem. I am trying to produce data to one of the kafka topics from a table in postgres, one of the column has type json, which is defined like this in the schema file (.avsc):

```
{
              "name": "details",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "string",
                  "connect.version": 1,
                  "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Json"
                }
              ],
              "default": null
            }
```

As per https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.9/connectors/postgresql.html#data-types it is  mapped to string data type of kafka connector.
The db column contains data like :

```
{"type":"User","id":"123","attributes":{"id":"123","state":"active"}}
```

But the topic produces it like this:

```
{\"type\":\"User\",\"id\":\"123\",\"attributes\":{\"id\":\"123\",\"state\":\"active\"}}
```

I want this to be produced as same string as passed, without the `\`. So, the expected output stream for the topic should have something like :

```
{"type":"User","id":"123","attributes":{"id":"123","state":"active"}}
```

What would be the best way to achieve it?

Comment: It ***is*** the same string. It is only escaped in the output medium you are viewing it in

Comment: Did't understanding the italics 'is' though, I realized that kafka treats this json value as a string and produces the data with '\'. Trying to produce it same as  the exact json will require efforts to create schema for details field, which is not worth it in this case. And most importantly it will be easier for the client to parse it and used it.

Comment: The schema is just a string for the details record. An actual JSON event would be a record type in AVSC with each internal field listed out. If you have a JSON column in Postgres, I don't think Debezium knows how to expand those

Comment: yes, you are right, it doesn't.

Comment: That being said, the only way to "fix it" would be to write some Kafka processor to parse out that string into a proper object

Comment: That can be done also by the client consuming the stream. Also, do you think it's a good idea for the client to do the json parsing on client side? I was wondering if it will be CPU intensive or can be done because kafka is not suggested to CPU intensive processing.

Comment: JSON Parsing isn't that CPU intensive. Not sure I understand, though. The CPU processing would be on an external client, not against Kafka